# DocuSign Embeded API Instant Sign Without Authentication from DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I need to create an application where user could sign the document on my website without any docusign authentication I guess just like LoanCo Sample Demo.

I'm using Embedded Signing and following the steps listed here, and getting the URI on EnvelopeViews: createRecipient call, but when I'm trying to access that URI it redirect to "/Signing/SessionTimeout.aspx" and says "SESSION ENDED" and then nothing happens, attaching the snapshot of "session ended" page.

Here is the create envelopes request JSON.

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
      "documentId": "1",
      "fileExtension": "pdf",
      "name": "PDF Doc"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Doc Sign",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "clientUserId",
        "email": "examble@email.com",
        "name": "Shah",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "tabLabel": "Sign Here",
              "xPosition": "100",
              "yPosition": "100"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my createRecipient request JSON.

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "email": "examle@email.com",
  "returnUrl": "https://localhost/index.php",
  "userName": "Shah"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the envelope is created, use the [createRecipient:EnvelopeViews](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) api to retrieve the Signing URL.

In your request you are missing the **clientUserId** parameter.

**Request**

```
{
  "userName": "Shah",
  "email": "examble@email.com",
  "clientUserId": "clientUserId",
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "returnUrl": "https://localhost/index.php"
}
```

Comment: But I want to use Embedded API, so that my users can sign on my website without signing in on docusign, am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes you are doing it right. Setting ClientUserId property on a recipient indicates that the recipient is an [embedded recipient](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning).